# laravel schema hasTable always returns false (Sql Server)

Tags: sql-server, laravel

for some reason i'm getting **false** when checking if an table exist in my **tempdb**, yes it does exist :)

tried:

```
Schema::hasTable('tempdb.dbo.tempreport')
Schema::hasTable('tempdb..tempreport')
```

this is what i want to do:

```
    if(Schema::hasTable('tempdb.dbo.tempreport') == false){
        Schema::create('tempdb.dbo.tempreport', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('airline');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `Schema::hasTable('tempreport')`?

Comment: @linuxartisan yes i have :(

Comment: Is this the case with all the tables, or just with `tempreport`?

Comment: any luck with this? Im having the same issue